# XSLT v1.0 transform grouped with multiple values to transform Filemaker Pro XML export to Excel spreadsheet

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, filemaker

I am new to xslt transforms and I am having some difficulty getting the result I want.
I am exporting a set of records from Filemaker Pro as XML with xslt transform to make a formatted ".xls" file.

This is the export order I am using from Filemaker Pro:

[image]

**GOALS:** 
1. I want each distinct `SupplierName` to have its own spreadsheet

2. Group the records within each spreadsheet by the `InvoiceNo`

**EDIT**: Using Martin's suggestions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" version="1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fmp set"
    xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:key name="group" match="fmp:ROW" use="fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA"/>

    <xsl:key name="nested-group" match="fmp:ROW" use="concat(fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA,'+',fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA)"/>


    <xsl:template match="fmp:FMPXMLRESULT">
        <Workbook
            xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
            xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
            xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
            xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
            xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
            <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
                <LastAuthor/>
                <Created/>
                <Version>11.9999</Version>
            </DocumentProperties>
            <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
                <WindowHeight>8190</WindowHeight>
                <WindowWidth>16380</WindowWidth>
                <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
                <WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY>
                <TabRatio>505</TabRatio>
                <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
                <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
            </ExcelWorkbook>
            <Styles>
                <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
                    <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
                    <Borders/>
                    <Font x:Family="Swiss"/>
                    <Interior/>
                    <NumberFormat/>
                    <Protection/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="Header">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="0"/>
                    <Borders/>
                    <Interior ss:Color="#666699" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
                    <Font ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:Size="26" ss:FontName="Verdana" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1" ss:Underline="Single"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="ColNames">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                    <Font ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:FontName="Verdana" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1"/>
                    <Interior ss:Color="#6C4E91" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="Data">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                    <Borders />
                    <Font ss:Size="14" ss:Color="#090A0E" ss:FontName="Verdana" x:Family="Swiss"/>
                    <Interior ss:Color="#D8E2E1" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="DataRight">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                    <Borders />
                    <Font ss:Size="14" ss:Color="#090A0E" ss:FontName="Verdana" x:Family="Swiss"/>
                    <Interior ss:Color="#D8E2E1" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="DataLeft">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                    <Borders />
                    <Font ss:Size="14" ss:Color="#090A0E" ss:FontName="Verdana" x:Family="Swiss"/>
                    <Interior ss:Color="#D8E2E1" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="DCurrency">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                    <Borders />
                    <Font ss:Color="#090A0E" ss:FontName="Verdana" x:Family="Swiss"/>
                    <Interior ss:Color="#D8E2E1" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="Group">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="0"/>
                    <Borders />
                    <Font ss:Size="16" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:FontName="Verdana" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1" ss:Underline="Single"/>
                    <Interior ss:Color="#FFA500" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="GroupRight">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="0"/>
                    <Borders />
                    <Font ss:Size="16" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:FontName="Verdana" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1"/>
                    <Interior ss:Color="#FFA500" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="GroupLeft">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="0"/>
                    <Borders />
                    <Font ss:Size="16" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:FontName="Verdana" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1"/>
                    <Interior ss:Color="#FFA500" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="GroupData">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="0"/>
                    <Borders />
                    <Font ss:Size="16" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:FontName="Verdana" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1"/>
                    <Interior ss:Color="#FFA500" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="Group2Right">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="0"/>
                    <Borders />
                    <Font ss:Size="16" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:FontName="Verdana" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="1"/>
                    <Interior ss:Color="#666699" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="Group2Data">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="0"/>
                    <Borders />
                    <Font ss:Size="16" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:FontName="Verdana" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="1"/>
                    <Interior ss:Color="#666699" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
                </Style>

                <Style ss:ID="Group2">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="0"/>
                    <Borders />
                    <Font ss:Size="14" ss:Color="#FFFFFF" ss:FontName="Verdana" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="1"/>
                    <Interior ss:Color="#666699" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="GroupSubTotalRight">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="0"/>
                    <Borders />
                    <Font ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#000000" ss:FontName="Verdana" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1"/>
                    <Interior ss:Color="#64A4E5" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="GroupSubTotal">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="0"/>
                    <Borders />
                    <Font ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#000000" ss:FontName="Verdana" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1"/>
                    <Interior ss:Color="#64A4E5" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
                </Style>
            </Styles>

            <xsl:for-each select="fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA)[1])]">

                <xsl:variable name="sheetName" select="fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA"/>

                <Worksheet ss:Name="{$sheetName}">
                    <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="15" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" >
                        <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="300"/>
                        <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="100"/>
                        <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="100"/>
                        <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="120"/>
                        <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="100"/>
                        <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="100"/>
                        <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="100"/>
                        <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="100"/>
                        <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="100"/>
                        <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="100"/>

                        <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="60">
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="Header">
                            </Cell>
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="Header">
                            </Cell>
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="Header">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">Purchases</Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="Header">
                            </Cell>
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="Header">
                            </Cell>
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="Header">
                            </Cell>
                        </Row>

                        <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="40" >
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="ColNames">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">ITEM</Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="ColNames">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">BARCODE</Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="ColNames">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">Qty</Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="ColNames">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">DISCOUNT</Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="ColNames">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">VAT</Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="ColNames">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">TOTAL COST</Data>
                            </Cell>

                        </Row>

                        <xsl:for-each select="key('group', fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('nested-group', concat(fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA,'+',fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA))[1])]">

                            <xsl:variable name="invoice" select="fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="type" select="fmp:COL[3]/fmp:DATA"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="receivedDate" select="fmp:COL[3]/fmp:DATA"/>

                            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="26" >
                                <Cell ss:StyleID="GroupLeft">
                                    <Data ss:Type="String">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Reveived On:',$receivedDate)"/>
                                    </Data>
                                </Cell>
                                <Cell ss:StyleID="GroupLeft">
                                    <Data ss:Type="String">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Invoice #:',$invoice)"/>
                                    </Data>
                                </Cell>
                                <Cell ss:StyleID="GroupLeft">

                                </Cell>
                                <Cell ss:StyleID="GroupLeft">

                                </Cell>
                                <Cell ss:StyleID="GroupRight">
                                    <Data ss:Type="String">Type:</Data>
                                </Cell>
                                <Cell ss:StyleID="GroupLeft">
                                    <Data ss:Type="String">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$type"/>
                                    </Data>
                                </Cell>
                            </Row>

                            <xsl:for-each select="key('group', fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('nested-group', concat(fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA,'+',fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA))[1])]">

                                <xsl:variable name="item" select="fmp:COL[10]/fmp:DATA"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="qty" select="fmp:COL[11]/fmp:DATA"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="cost" select="fmp:COL[12]/fmp:DATA"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="discount" select="fmp:COL[13]/fmp:DATA"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="VAT" select="fmp:COL[14]/fmp:DATA"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="itemTotal" select="fmp:COL[15]/fmp:DATA"/>


                                <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="22">

                                    <Cell ss:StyleID="Data">
                                        <Data ss:Type="String">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$item"/>
                                        </Data>
                                    </Cell>
                                    <Cell ss:StyleID="Data">
                                        <Data ss:Type="String">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$qty"/>
                                        </Data>
                                    </Cell>
                                    <Cell ss:StyleID="Data">
                                        <Data ss:Type="String">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$cost"/>
                                        </Data>
                                    </Cell>
                                    <Cell ss:StyleID="Data">
                                        <Data ss:Type="String" >
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$discount"/>
                                        </Data>
                                    </Cell>
                                    <Cell ss:StyleID="Data">
                                        <Data ss:Type="String">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$VAT"/>
                                        </Data>
                                    </Cell>
                                    <Cell ss:StyleID="Data">
                                        <Data ss:Type="String">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$itemTotal"/>
                                        </Data>
                                    </Cell>

                                </Row>

                            </xsl:for-each>
                            <xsl:variable name="Subtotal" select="fmp:COL[5]/fmp:DATA"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="Discount" select="fmp:COL[6]/fmp:DATA"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="NetCost" select="fmp:COL[7]/fmp:DATA"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="TotalVAT" select="fmp:COL[8]/fmp:DATA"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="InvoiceTotal" select="fmp:COL[9]/fmp:DATA"/>


                            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="26">
                                <Cell> </Cell>
                                <Cell> </Cell>
                                <Cell> </Cell>
                                <Cell> </Cell>

                                <Cell ss:StyleID="GroupSubTotalRight">
                                    <Data ss:Type="String">Subtotal:</Data>
                                </Cell>
                                <Cell ss:StyleID="GroupSubTotal">
                                    <Data ss:Type="String" >
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$Subtotal"/>
                                    </Data>
                                </Cell>
                            </Row>

                            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="26">
                                <Cell> </Cell>
                                <Cell> </Cell>
                                <Cell> </Cell>
                                <Cell> </Cell>

                                <Cell ss:StyleID="GroupSubTotalRight">
                                    <Data ss:Type="String">Discount:</Data>
                                </Cell>
                                <Cell ss:StyleID="GroupSubTotal">
                                    <Data ss:Type="String" >
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$Discount"/>
                                    </Data>
                                </Cell>
                            </Row>

                            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="26">
                                <Cell> </Cell>
                                <Cell> </Cell>
                                <Cell> </Cell>
                                <Cell> </Cell>

                                <Cell ss:StyleID="GroupSubTotalRight">
                                    <Data ss:Type="String">Net Cost:</Data>
                                </Cell>
                                <Cell ss:StyleID="GroupSubTotal">
                                    <Data ss:Type="String" >
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$NetCost"/>
                                    </Data>
                                </Cell>
                            </Row>

                            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="26">
                                <Cell> </Cell>
                                <Cell> </Cell>
                                <Cell> </Cell>
                                <Cell> </Cell>

                                <Cell ss:StyleID="GroupSubTotalRight">
                                    <Data ss:Type="String">VAT:</Data>
                                </Cell>
                                <Cell ss:StyleID="GroupSubTotal">
                                    <Data ss:Type="String" >
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$TotalVAT"/>
                                    </Data>
                                </Cell>
                            </Row>

                            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="26">
                                <Cell> </Cell>
                                <Cell> </Cell>
                                <Cell> </Cell>
                                <Cell> </Cell>

                                <Cell ss:StyleID="GroupSubTotalRight">
                                    <Data ss:Type="String">Total:</Data>
                                </Cell>
                                <Cell ss:StyleID="GroupSubTotal">
                                    <Data ss:Type="String" >
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$InvoiceTotal"/>
                                    </Data>
                                </Cell>
                            </Row>
                        </xsl:for-each>


                    </Table>

                    <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
                        <PageSetup>
                            <Layout x:Orientation="Landscape"/>
                            <Header x:Margin="0.1701388888888889"/>
                            <Footer x:Margin="0.15972222222222221" x:Data=" "/>
                            <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.16944444444444443" x:Left="0.2" x:Right="0.19027777777777777" x:Top="0.4604166666666667"/>
                        </PageSetup>
                        <FitToPage/>
                        <Print>
                            <FitHeight>0</FitHeight>
                            <ValidPrinterInfo/>
                            <PaperSizeIndex>9</PaperSizeIndex>
                            <HorizontalResolution>300</HorizontalResolution>
                            <VerticalResolution>300</VerticalResolution>
                        </Print>
                        <Zoom>85</Zoom>
                        <Selected/>
                        <Panes>
                            <Pane>
                                <Number>3</Number>
                                <ActiveRow>1</ActiveRow>
                                <ActiveCol>1</ActiveCol>
                            </Pane>
                        </Panes>
                        <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
                        <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
                    </WorksheetOptions>
                </Worksheet>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </Workbook>
    </xsl:template>
```

**EDIT**: Here is the result in Excel

[image]

I would greatly appreciate any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with two keys

```
<xsl:key name="group" match="fmp:ROW" use="fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA"/>

<xsl:key name="nested-group" match="fmp:ROW" use="concat(fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA,'+',fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA)"/>
```

and then change

```
        <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW/fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA)">
```

to

```
        <xsl:for-each select="fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA)[1])]">
```

and the inner

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('group', .)">
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('group', fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('nested-group', concat(fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA,'+',fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA))[1])]">
```

You will have to adapt some paths as the context nodes are `fmp:ROW` elements.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Your suggestions fixed the loops. However I am only getting 1 item(row) per invoice.  I have updated the question to include your suggestions and I added a 3rd loop although not sure how to access it correctly.Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain what kind of Excel XML you want to create for a nested group by invoice? Or perhaps change third `for-each` to process all items in the group with e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="key('nested-group', concat(fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA,'+',fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA)">...</xsl:for-each>`.

Comment: Yes! That did it.Thank you very much Martin